# Remove jQuery generated content with on()

Tags: jquery

I have some markup like this:

```
<div class="large-image">
    <img src="foo.jpg" class="original-size"> <--This persists
    <img src="foo-fullsize.jpg" class="zoomed"> <--injected by jQuery zoom plugin
    <img src="bar-fullsize.jpg" class="zoomed"> <--also injected
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <a href="foo-fullsize.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="foo-thumb.jpg"></a>
    <a href="bar-fullsize.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="bar-thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I have some code like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('a.thumb').click(function(){
      $('#main-image').zoom({url: this.href}); // jQuery zoom
   });
});
```

Every time I click a thumb link, the zoom plugin injects a new image into the `<div class="large-image">` container. I would like to be able to remove all existing images with class zoomed before a new one is created. I know I need to use on() to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it to work with the generated images.

Comment: $('a.thumb').on('click', function() { $('img.zoomed').remove(); });

Comment: Do you want to remove all images in `div.large-image`? Because that jQuery plugin creates extra `img` elements

Comment: @Alexander I don't want to remove ALL img elements, only the ones generated by the plugin (which have a class of "zoomed")

Comment: @Garrett, according to the original plugin they SHOULD have a `zoomImg` classname instead

Comment: @Alexander they do, I changed it to "zoomed" for the example.

Comment: It's time for you to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a real live example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('a.thumb').on('click', function() {
    $('img.zoomed', this).remove(); 
  });
});
```

This will remove all `.zoomed` images relative to the thumbnail clicked. If you want to target every `.zoomed` image on the page, you'll want to drop the context:

```
$('img.zoomed').
```

---

### Edit

I didn't realise it was generated content. Give this a whirl:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.thumb', function() {
    $('img.zoomed').remove(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the images that are generated with my plugin (jQuery zoom http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom). I'll update my example for clarity.

Comment: There we go! Other than reversing your event and element parameters :)

Answer (score 2):

The selector `$('img.zoomed')` will match all the present `<img>` elements with a `zoomed` classname at the moment of execution indifferently of the way they were added.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('a.thumb').click(function(){
      $('img.zoomed').remove();
   });
});
```

---

Since the jQuery Zoom plugin creates extra elements next to the original images. You should try removing all `<img>` elements under `div.large-image` instead.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('a.thumb').click(function(){
      $('div.large-image img').remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: This does not remove the images generated by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `.remove()` method:

```
$("img[class='zoomed']").remove();
```

or:

```
$("img.zoomed").remove();
```